# Получить содержимое attachments -> video [JSON] Java

Tags: java, android, json, vkontakte-api

Имеется следующая структура JSON:

```
{
"response": {
"count": 10,
"items": [{
"id": 104755,
"from_id": -1,
"owner_id": -1,
"date": 1483803000,
"marked_as_ads": 0,
"post_type": "postpone",
"text": "Message",
"can_edit": 1,
"created_by": 1,
"can_publish": 1,
"can_delete": 1,
"attachments": [{
"type": "video",
"video": {
"id": 1,
"owner_id": -1,
"title": "Title",
"duration": 6,
"description": "description",
"date": 1483801275,
"comments": 0,
"views": 17,
"photo_130": "https://pp.vk.me/...ideo/s_84ca8f4e.jpg",
"photo_320": "https://pp.vk.me/...ideo/l_90217297.jpg",
"photo_640": "https://pp.vk.me/...ideo/y_7c611865.jpg",
"access_key": "43cbb785c00ac1bb0f",
"platform": "Coub",
"can_edit": 1,
"can_add": 1
}
}],
"post_source": {
"type": "api"
},
"comments": {
"count": 0,
"can_post": 0
}
}],
"profiles": [],
"groups": [{
"id": 80682837,
"name": "Name",
"screen_name": "Name",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "page",
"is_admin": 1,
"admin_level": 3,
"is_member": 1,
"photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...4ea/bZj_J5bL_EM.jpg",
"photo_100": "https://pp.vk.me/...4e9/55T6C3xKJkA.jpg",
"photo_200": "https://pp.vk.me/...4e8/a_soitbpt3g.jpg"
}, {
"id": 1,
"name": "Name",
"screen_name": "club1",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 1,
"admin_level": 3,
"is_member": 1,
"photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...500/k6TkTmhCSiA.jpg",
"photo_100": "https://pp.vk.me/...4ff/Cb8hMKo9nSU.jpg",
"photo_200": "https://pp.vk.me/...4fe/6jafptAHifc.jpg"
}]
}
}
```

Не могу подобраться к значению в **"items": [{"attachments": [{"video": {"photo_640"}}]}]**.
Объясните пожалуйста, как добраться то до него?

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.json.get("response");
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject post = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
        //
        Posts mv = new Posts(post.getString("text").substring(post.getString("text").indexOf('\n') + 1), GetUTC(Long.parseLong(post.getString("date"))), post.getString("id"), "photo_640.jpg");
        mvList.add(mv);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Покажите валидный json.

Comment: По ссылке, наверное, должен отобразиться результат выполнения запроса, но без авторизации он недоступен. Там просто доки по `wall.get`.

Comment: Отредактировал пост.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если по порядку, то так:

```
JSONObject response = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
JSONObject item0 = items.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray attachments = item0.getJSONArray("attachments");
JSONObject attachment0 = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject video = attachment0.getJSONObject("video");
String videoLink = video.getString("photo_640");
```